# @PreAuthorize(permitAll) still requires authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following example method in my `Repository` (with `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation):

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("permitAll")
@PostAuthorize("permitAll")
public Iterable<User> findAll();
```

But I'm still getting `401 Unauthorized`, event when I add those `permitAll` annotation to whole Repository interface.

I got this as my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I suppose this takes precedence over those method annotations, bu I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe you missed parenthesis in `permitAll`. Try `permitAll()`

Comment: Do you really need these annotations? What happens when you remove them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Method security is applied after the web security filter.

Since you have `anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()` in your configuration, your `findAll` method will never be hit. `anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()` means that all attempts to access a web endpoint that does no have have some from of full user authentication on it will fail.

From the JavaDoc

> Specify that URLs are allowed by users who have authenticated and were
>   not "remembered".

You will need to add an additional path in your web security, some like.

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, '/somePath').permitAll()
         .and()
            .httpBasic()
         .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Is it really the only way? I mean keeping the path in two places is messy. Is there no way to annotate endpoints which are to be unsecured?

Comment: The problem is that it is two completely separate security systems that run at different times.

Comment: Is there still now way to have both? This basically means that we can forget `@PreAuthorize()` etc completely.

Comment: This answer is pretty old, perhaps things have changed in the past 3 years? You could have both, but you need to understand what runs at which stage

Comment: The authorizeRequest list is processed in order, and takes the first match ... so the permitAll should go above the fullyAutheticated for this to work, I would imagine